# Sonata editable block

Tags: symfony, block, symfony-sonata

Is there a way to make a Sonata Block editable? I have seen that there is a method named `buildEditForm` mentioned in the docs (http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/your_first_block.html#form-edition), but I don't know how this form is displayed, and how to manage the editing of the block.

Answer (score 0):

The `buildEditForm` method is used when editing a Block from the Admin ([`SonataAdminBundle`](http://www.github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle)). Once the AdminBundle is set up, you will be able to edit your blocks amongst your pages (you'll need pagebundle as well for this).